# How to Fix Vuejs: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'creditData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

i created a for-loop in mount function to extract data from a vuejs store state which gets its data from **firebaseOnAuthChanged** but each time i run the page i get:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'creditData' of >undefined

i tried accessing the data directly with
`this.userProfile.transactions.creditData[0].amount`
i got the data to display but with the loop i couldn't

here is the script...

```
import LineChart from '@/components/LineChart'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { store } from '@/store'
export default {
name: 'dashboard',
components: {
    'line-chart': LineChart
  },
 data () {
    return {
      totalCredit: 0,
      totalDebit: 0,
      totalInterest: 0,
      test: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({ userProfile: 'userProfile', currentUser: 'currrentUser' 
})
  },
  mounted: function () {
    if (this.userProfile) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.userProfile.transactions.creditData.lenght; 
i++) {
        this.totalCredit += 
this.userProfile.transactions.creditData[i].amount
        this.test.push(this.userProfile.transactions.creditData[i].amount)
      }
      for (var x = 0; x <= this.userProfile.transactions.debitData.lenght; 
x++) {
        this.totalDebit += this.userProfile.transactions.debitData[x].amount
      }
      if (this.totalCredit >= 25000) {
        this.totalInterest = this.totalCredit / 100 * 1.98
      } else { this.totalInterest = this.totalCredit / 100 * 1.5 }
    }
  }
}
```

here is my store script...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const fb = require('@/firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.use(Vuex)

fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
   store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
   store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')

    fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
      store.commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
     })
   }
})

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentUser: null,
    userProfile: {}
  },
  actions: {
    clearData ({ commit }) {
      commit('setCurrentUser', null)
      commit('setUserProfile', {})
    },
    fetchUserProfile ({ commit, state }) {
      fb.usersCollection
        .doc(state.currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then(res => {
          commit('setUserProfile', res.data())
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message)
        })
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setCurrentUser (state, val) {
      state.currentUser = val
    },
    setUserProfile (state, val) {
      state.userProfile = val
    }
  }
})
```

here is viewport where i call the data...

```
<h3> {{totalCredit}}</h3>
<h3> {{totalDebit}}</h3>
<h3> {{totalInterest}}</h3>
```

this is the format if the data am recieving from firestore if i call the data directly from the view port `{{ userProfile.transactions.creditData }}`

```
[ { 
   "amount": 1000, 
   "date": { "seconds": 1545491831, "nanoseconds": 993000000 }, 
   "status": "successful", 
   "transID": 123456789 
 } ]
```

i expected the result of `{{ totalCredit }}` to be 1000 or more if there is more transaction entries

Comment: You should also add the code of your store

Comment: @nemesv i used that already didnt work....

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i added the store code